# нужно отловить нажатую клавишу и вывести ее в out-1

Tags: javascript

```
let out = document.querySelector('.out-1');
let input = document.querySelector('.i-1').onkeydown = function f1 (event){

  if(event.key == true){
    out.innerHTML;
  }
  else{
    out.innerHTML = 'ошибка';
  }
  console.log('chareCode:' + event.charCode);
  console.log('code:' + event.code);
  console.log('key:' + event.key);
  console.log('keyCode:' + event.keyCode);
  console.log(event);
}

 <div>
    <input type="text" class="i-1">
  </div>
  <div class="out-1"></div>
```

Comment: а в чём собственно вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.charCode` уже не рекомендуется использовать.

```js
const out = document.querySelector('.out-1');

document.querySelector('.i-1').onkeydown = function(event) {
  out.innerHTML = event.key;
  console.log('chareCode:' + event.key.charCodeAt(0));
  console.log('code:' + event.code);
  console.log('key:' + event.key);
  console.log('keyCode:' + event.keyCode);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="i-1">
<div class="out-1"></div>
```

Comment: как я не додумался)спасибо)

Comment: @ВадимУманский, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

```js
const In = document.getElementById("in"),
      Out = document.getElementById("out");

In.addEventListener("keypress", event => Out.innerText = event.key)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in" autocomplete="false" />
<div id="out"></div>
```